# How do I setup a TFS 2010 Workflow build process similar to my current NAnt process

Tags: tfs, msbuild, workflow, tfsbuild

I have a build process is in NAnt and resembles the following structure (a lot has been abreviated). I'm having some confussion on what I can put into Workflow from my NAnt Script and what I should convert to MSBuild(or not).  Various targets within the NAnt script will set properties, copy files, delete files, make calls to external processes such as compiling VB6 projects. Any tips on porting this over to workflow would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you have questions.

```
<?xml ... >
<project ...>

  <!-- Get and combine paths -->
  <properties name="" value=""/>
  <properties name="" value=""/>
  <properties name="" value=""/>
  .
  .
  .
  . 

  <target name="Main">
   <!--Set Log Folder Name to include date and time.
   <mkdir dir="${LogDir}"/>

   <call target="DeleteTicketsFile"/> 
   <call target="GetTickets"/> 
   <call target="WriteTicketsToFile"/> 
   <call target="WriteProperties"/> 
   <call target="DeleteFolders" failonerror="true"/> 
   <call target="GetLatest" failonerror="true"/>
   <call target="BuildDOTNETSolution" failonerror="true"/>
   <call target="BuildVB6Projects" failonerror="true"/>
   . 
   .
   .
  <target name="BuildDOTNETSolution">

    <property name="ProjectName" value="Localcache" />

    <echo message="VCVarsAllBatFile = ${VCVarsAllBatFile}"/>
    <exec program="${VCVarsAllBatFile}"/>

    <property name="dotnetSlnFile" value="${path::combine(ProductDir, 'dot.net.sln')}"/>
    <property name="dotnetOutFile" value="${path::combine(LogDir, 'dotnet.out.txt')}"/>

    <echo message="dotnetSlnFile = ${dotnetSlnFile}"/>
    <echo message="dotnetOutFile = ${dotnetOutFile}"/>

    <delete file="${dotnetOutFile}" if="${file::exists(dotnetOutFile)}" failonerror="false"/>

    <!-- Build .NET solution in Release mode -->
    <exec program="${DevenvExe}">
      <environment>
        <variable name="COMSUPPORT" value="N"/>
        <variable name="COPYEXECENV" value="N"/>
      </environment>
      <arg value='"${dotnetSlnFile}"'/>
      <arg value='/Rebuild "Release|Any CPU"'/>
      <arg value='/Out "${dotnetOutFile}"'/>
    </exec>
  </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to replace NAnt entirely and use TFS Build Workflow to customize and maintain your build.  That said, if your NAnt script it pretty involved that can take some time (especially if you're new to TFS Workflow-based builds).  My suggestion to start is to simply have the Workflow Build use the InvokeProcess Activity to execute the NAnt build via the command-line (nant.exe).  Then you can incrementally move pieces of the build out of the NAnt script into the workflow.

For example, the entire BuildDotNETSolution target looks like it doesn't do anything special, all this is already included in the DefaultTemplate.xaml build workflow, you simply specify the SolutionsToBuild argument in the Build Definition.

Comment: Yes. The plan is to replace NAnt entirely. I'm trying to wrap my head around how the whole thing works with Workflow and what we will need to do to port everything from NAnt. Are there any tutorials that suggest how to port from NAnt?  Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be anything specific for porting from NAnt, it's just a matter of understanding how to do things in Workflow, then re-implementing your build process in WF.  The best TFS Build tutorial I've come across is the ALM Rangers Guidance on CodePlex: http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/82962